How to find eigenvectors, finding a base f in which linear operator has diagonal matrix and determining the operator in that new basis ([L]_f)
Original question where all details are available: How to find a matrix, characteristic and minimal polynomial of a linear operator?
Here I will only copy the results from that question.
$$L(g(X))=g(0)(-1-2X+4X^2)+g^`(1)(-1+2X^2)+g^{``}(0)(-X+\frac{1}{2}X^2)$$, standard basis $e=[1, X, X^2]$
Matrix:
$$ A=L_e =  \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
-2 & 0 & -2 \\
4 & 2 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
characteristic and minimal polynomials:
$(\lambda-1)^2 \cdot(\lambda-2)$
$(\lambda-1)\cdot(\lambda-2)$
eigenvalues: $1, 1, 2$
Process of finding eigenvectors:
We replace each of these eigenvalues for $\lambda$ (same equation as finding the characteristic polynomial)
so for $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$, $\lambda_3=2$
$A-\lambda E$(some write $I$ instead of $E$, it's the same thing)
$A-\lambda_1 E$=$\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -1 &  -2\\
-2 & -1 &  -2\\
4 & 2 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
Now, it's pretty obvious that the solution to this system will include 2 random variables, let's call them $\alpha$ and $\beta$, both $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$
We will have only one equation with three variables, $-2x -1y -2z = 0$. Here $\alpha$ and $\beta$ come into play.
Let's say $x=\alpha$ and $y=\beta$, that means $z=-\alpha-\frac{\beta}{2}$
Now, vector $x_1=\beta(0, 1, -\frac{1}{2})$ for $\alpha=0$
$x_2=\alpha(1,0,-1)$ for $\beta=0$
and finally $x_3=\alpha(1,0,-1)+\beta(0,1,-\frac{1}{2})$
but that's just the first case when \lambda=1
Now same thing for $A-\lambda_3 E$=$\begin{pmatrix}
-3 & -1 &  -2\\
-2 & -2 &  -2\\
4 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
$-3x-y-2z=0$
$-2x-2y-2z=0$
$4x+2y+3z=0$
...and for this one result is $x_1=\alpha(1,1,-2)$
Basis $f=[(1,0,-x^2), (0,x,-\frac{1}{2}x^2), (1, x,-2x^2)]$
Formula for diagonalization is: $A=XDX^{-1}$ where $A$ is our starting matrix,
$D= \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 &  0\\
0 & \lambda_2 &  0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
and $X,X^{-1}$ are made out of the eigenvectors (basis $f$). How do I know in which order to place them? Like for example in diagonal matrix D, does it matter in what order I place the characteristic values? Same question goes for the basis, which one of these 3 vectors goes first in the basis (and in the first column of X)?
$X= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &  1\\
0 & 1 &  1\\
-1 & -\frac{1}{2} & -2\\
\end{pmatrix}$
and its inverse
$X^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 &  2\\
2 & 2 &  2\\
-2 & -1 & -2\\
\end{pmatrix}$
swapping this into formula $A=XDX^{-1}$ gives me the exact matrix $A$ so I guess this part is correct.
Now, last part about $[L]_f$ is a bit complicated.
Given operator from the beginning:
$$L(g(X))=g(0)(-1-2X+4X^2)+g^`(1)(-1+2X^2)+g^{``}(0)(-X+\frac{1}{2}X^2)$$
Now matrix needs to be created in this new basis:
$f=[1-x^2, x-\frac{1}{2}x^2, 1+x-2x^2]$.
But simplifying the operator equation this time, I get $a(-1-2x+x^4)+b(-1+2x^2)+c(-2-2x+5x^2)$
Just to show what i was doing, here's example for the first one:
$L_{f_1}= a(-1-2x+4x^2)-c(-2-2x+5x^2)=1-x^2$
And from here, I would make a system like: $\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2 +\gamma f_3 = 1-x^2$, here $\alpha f_1=1$, $\beta f_2=0$ and $\gamma f_3=-x^2$ and upon solving this system I would get the vector coordinates for the first column and then repeat the process for the others. I'm not sure if this approach is correct but I know there's also another approach which is called "change of basis" or "transition matrix". From what I have found, this approach seems confusing to me as I could only find theoretic ideas and without real examples.

You don't have four vectors but 3. You found a basis of 2 vectors  $(1,0,-1),(0,1,-\frac{1}{2})$ for
the eigenspace $\ker(A-I)$ and a basis of 1 vector  $  (1,1,-2)$ for the eigenspace $\ker(A-2I)$. These 3 vectors are your eigenbasis for $A$. They are the 3 columns of $X$.

Oh okay so what would be the next step? I'm kinda confused about the $[L]_f$ notation, is it a matrix in basis f or a linear operator in basis f? If I understood you correctly, we have found 2 different bases? And now we use one of them to construct another operator?

I don't know the statement you were given, involving this notation, so I can only conjecture that $f$ is the eigenbasis of my previous comment (or any similar eigenbasis for $A$), and $[L]_f$ is the matrix of $L$ in this new basis (hence it is a diagonal matrix). We haven't found '2 different bases' (of $\Bbb R^3$); we have built one, as the union of the respective basis of the two eigensubspaces. And we do not construct any other operator.

Does that mean that the new basis $f=[1-x^2, x-\frac{1}{2}x^2, 1+x-2x^2]$? And from there matrix is made out of $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ placed into columns as you said in the previous comment? This will also indicate that it's a $3\times 3$ matrix but I guess we already knew this.

Yes $f$ is this. The $3\times3$ matrix made of the $f_i$'s in columns is $X$, as explained in my first comment above. This is not $[L]_f$. The latter is (supposedly) described in my 2nd comment.

@AnneBauval Hello, I edited my post. Kindly check if I made some errors in calculation or if it's a bad concept im going for.

Your $f,X$ is allright if you choose to order the eigenvalues in $D$ accordingly (of course, you may permute simultaneously the vectors in $f$, i.e. the columns of $X$, and the eigenvalues; you may even choose a different eigenbasis, as long as the order of the eigenvalues in $D$ corresponds). $[L]_f$ is simply $D$.

I think I figured out how to solve the last part. So, it is required to make a matrix of a given linear operator but in this new basis $f=[1-x^2, x-\frac{1}{2}x^2, 1+x-2x^2]$.
First column (we  swap x for the first basis vector, in this case $f_1 = 1-x^2$): $L_{f_1}= 1(-1-2x+4x^2)-2(-1+2x^2)-2(-x+\frac{1}{2})$
further, I got $1-x^2$. Now, $\alpha(f_1)+\beta(f_2)+\gamma(f_3)=1-x^2$
The system from here is $\alpha+\gamma=1$; $\beta+\gamma=0$; $-\alpha-\frac{\beta}{2}-2\gamma=-1$ Solving the system, I got $\alpha=1, \beta=0, \gamma=0$. In other words, $f_1=(1,0,0)$ and this is the first column of the matrix. The same process applies to $f_2$ and $f_3$ where I get $f_2=(-2,-1,2)$ and $f_3=(8, 0, -2)$.
Final matrix $[L]_f$ is $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  -2& 8 \\
 0&  -1& 0 \\
 0& 2 &  -2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
